# Can I use mongoDB without a web service layer in between with Mobile devices?

Tags: ios, mongodb

Currently I am using MySQL + RoR combination for storing data of my iOS application.
I use Core Data for offline storage.

So I have made a lot of APIs or various CRUD like operations.

Given the fact that Mongo stores entities as JSONs, and it also has a REST interface, is it possible to use Mongo without a web service in front of it to store data using its own REST API?

If No then whats the problem? Is it because of security concerns or its not possible at all.

If Yes, is it OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both concerns that you've raised are valid:

- The MongoDB `--rest` feature is a [simple readonly interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-SimpleRESTInterface) (no support for insert/update/remove operations).
- It's also poor practice from a security point of view to expose your database server directly on the internet.

Suggested approaches would be to either:

1) Use (or build) a secure [REST API](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-RESTInterfaces) for your application

2) Use a [hosted MongoDB service](http://www.10gen.com/partners/cloudhosting) that provides a secure REST API.

Comment: Thanks, thats how the current approach is. I was just wondering if we can directly send query to the database nd get the result than making so many APIs :P